# Matching of values through user input

Tags: javascript, beginner, html5

I'm attempting to make a program that will take user input and match it to one of multiple predetermined values. I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to do this, or if there's any way that I can set the values without hard-coding them, such as making them dependent on a certain separate form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Input Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div class="not">
                <p>Please type your input into the box below.</p>
                <input type="number" id="input">
                <button type="submit" onclick="Output()">Submit</button>
                <pre id="OutputHere">Type an input first!</pre>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    window.onload = function() {
            if (document.getElementById("input").value != null) {
                Output();
            };
       };

        function Output() {
            var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
            switch (input) {
                case "1":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML= "13";
                    break;
                case "2":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML= "1";
                    break;
                case "3":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = "14"
                    break;
                case "4":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = "8"
                    break;
                case "5":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = "9"
                    break;
                case "6":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = "14"
                    break;
                case "7":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = "3"
                    break;
                case "8":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = "4"
                    break;
                case "9":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = "9"
                    break;
                case "10":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = "3"
                    break;
                case "11":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = "13"
                    break;
                case "12":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = "1"
                    break;
                case "13":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = "5"
                    break;
                case "14":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = "4"
                    break;
                case "15":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = "3"
                    break;
                case "16":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = "3"
                    break;
                case "17":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = "15"
                    break;
                case "18":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = "2"
                    break;
                case "19":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = "1214"
                    break;
                case "20":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = "10"
                    break;
                case "21":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = "13"
                    break;
                case "22":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = "9"
                    break;
                case "23":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = "12"
                    break;
                case "24":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = "6"
                    break;
                case "25":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = "10"
                    break;
                case "26":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = "14"
                    break;
                case "27":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = "11"
                    break;
                case "28":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = "13"
                    break;
                case "29":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = "6"
                    break;
                case "30":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = "6"
                    break;
                case "31":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = "7"
                    break;
                case "34":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = "5"
                    break;
                case "35":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = "13"
                    break;
                case "36":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = "1"
                    break;
                case "37":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = "3"
                    break;
                case "38":
                    document.getElementById("OutputHerre").innerHTML = "4"
                    break;
                default:
                    document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = "I'm sorry, we didn't understand that input. Please enter a valid input and try again.
                    break;
            };
        };
        addEventListener("submit", Output());
```

Comment: Create a js object with your matches, like `var matches = { "1": "13" }`, it's better, then to search do `matches[document.getElementById("input").value]` will return the value and if undefined prompt your message.

Comment: @MiguelLattuada you should place your comment in an answer at is a good point of a review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All functions should be defined in a *script* tag placed in the head of the HTML.

Instead you put it in the same tag where you use at the end of the HTML document.

The practice to place functions first is because in javascript the function are available just after the definition.

Have a function listener for the *onload* event placed at the end of the HTML document is meaningless.

As the HTML load elements sequencially, when you got the end of the page you already have the document loaded.

The proper use is when you place the *script* tag in the head section, as this part is loaded before the page is ready.

A good practice is to use some module pattern to wrap up your code and avoid to have global variables.

Even if the code is short you could use a function to contain your code:

```
!function (w) {
    w.MyModule = {
       name: "MyModuleName",
       version: "1.2.3"
    };

    function Output() {
       // ... some code here ....
    }

    w.MyModule.Output = Output;

}(window);
```

This anonymous function is executed automatically and the *window* object is passed ad parameter.

So you could now use your module in all the places you need:

```
MyModule.Output();
```

or

```
window.MyModule.Output();
```

About your *Output()* function.

Instead to rewrite the *document.getElementById...* staff all the time you should use a temporary variable:

```
var outputHere = "";

switch (input) {
      case "1":
          outputHere= "13";
          break;
      case "2":
          outputHere = "1";
          break;
      case "3":
          outputHere = "14"
          break;
      case "4":
    ...
 }

 document.getElementById("OutputHere").innerHTML = outputHere;
```

Another improvement you could do is to place the id in a configuration variable, defined in your scope (the previous module function).

```
var outputHereDivId = "OutputHere";

// ... inside the function...

document.getElementById(outputHereDivId).innerHTML = ...
```

The advantage is not just the easy way you can change the div ids in future, also the fast capability to change your code, refactoring or enancing it.

About the naming conventions.

In javascript the function start with lower case letter.

Then it's not clear to me why you bind the *click* and the *submit* events.

And even you need to do that, why use the *addEventListener* for one and put the other in the HTML?

You should follow just one way: all in HTML or all in javascript code.

The better should be using javascript code to bind the events.

I think bind the *click* event it's enough.

And the *addEventListener()* should be placed inside the *onload*, now it works just because it is in a tag at the end of the HTML page.